# in the context of representation theory, what is $\phi_{\alpha, V}$? (see details)

Tags: representation-theory

I have a group $G$ and a function $\alpha: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which is a class function.  Also, there is a representation $V$ of $G$.  What would this notation mean?

$\phi_{\alpha, V}$

I know it's a function, but what is it a function between and what are its properties?

Is this a standard notation for something or could it be personal notation used by whoever took the notes/taught the class?

Comment: What do the notes say about this function?

Comment: Not much, just that it exists.  There is a an exercise that states: show that if $\alpha$ is not a class function, then there exists a representation $V$ for which this function is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Ok, given that extra context, it is almost certain the function $V\to V$ given by the action of $\alpha$ (where we view a representation as a module over the group algebra which is identified with the set of functions $G\to \mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Does this map have a special name?  I would like to research it.